# UITableView inserting section at top while scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am inserting new section (section contains 3 cells) top of UITableView while SCROLLING TOP.

```
      [_mainTable beginUpdates];
      [_mainTable insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
      [_mainTable endUpdates];
```

Section gets inserting properly. But it takes me top of Table i.e. cell 0 or row 0. I want this transaction to be smooth. I can insert

```
[_mainTable scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:1] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:NO];
```

after endUpdates but it shows quick jerk because it takes you top of Table then suddenly scroll it to your last position.

How can i make it smooth.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I haven't done exhaustive testing on this, but this seems promising:

1. Identify `NSIndexPath` of one of the visible cells.
2. Get its `rectForRowAtIndexPath`.
3. Get the current `contentOffset` of the table, itself.
4. Add the section, but call `reloadData` instead of `insertSections` (which prevents jarring scrolling).
5. Get the updated `rectForRowAtIndexPath` that you got in step 2.
6. Update `contentOffset` by the difference of the result from step 5 and that of step 2.

Thus:

```
[self.sections insertObject:newSection atIndex:0];  // this is my model backing my table

NSIndexPath *oldIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows[0];    // 1
CGRect before = [self.tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:oldIndexPath];       // 2
CGPoint contentOffset = [self.tableView contentOffset];                    // 3
[self.tableView reloadData];                                               // 4
NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:oldIndexPath.row inSection:oldIndexPath.section + 1];
CGRect after = [self.tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:newIndexPath];        // 5
contentOffset.y += (after.origin.y - before.origin.y);
self.tableView.contentOffset = contentOffset;                              // 6
```

Comment: Thank you very much mate. I was struggling with this for long.

Comment: Although above code works like charm but for my personal understanding i didnot get point 5. Why we need old rectangle here ? I would be very thankful if you clear it

Comment: @mann I was just trying to see how much one of the visible rows shifted down. So I get the rect for a visible row before the insertion and again, after, and then use the difference between the `y` values to adjust the `contentOffset` should be so that row appears in the same place as before.

Comment: wow, thank you so much, just found this and is exactly what i need. thanks!

Comment: thanks again. not sure if this will help others or not, but here's some additional commentary that helped me:

// 1 get index path (section, row) of TOP visible row on screen
// 2 determine how far down that row is
// 3 how far scrolled down in the list are you
// 4.5(newIndexPath line) determine index path(section, row) of row after refresh. ASSUMPTION: only one section added above and no new updates to existing section
// 5 how far down is new row
// 6 update contentOffset to shift tableview down to where story is now

Comment: I know, this is an old question, but it's still working great. Thank you.
In my case, I had to make sure to implement 
`-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
otherwise the `after` rect had the wrong `origin.y`
I guess this depends on where you actually perform the row insertion. In my case it was `scrollViewDidScroll`