# How to postion tableView to the last inserted section SMOOTH

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

**EDIT:**

I found this SO thread.

### [UITableView inserting section at top while scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18164519/uitableview-inserting-section-at-top-while-scrolling)

- I have a tableView
- I load it with 5 sections initially
- Then I scroll up and when section 0 and row 0 is displayed, I load the next 5 sections and insert in table view using

> ```
> [self beginUpdates];
>
> [self deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
>
> [self insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
>
> [self insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
>
> [self insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:2] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
>
> [self endUpdates];
> ```

However my problem is the tableView gets position at section 0 and row 0 after the inserts

but I want to position at last row of last new section inserted (which is section 2 in code above)

I tried this both inside and outside begin/end updates

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:2];
[self scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath
            atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
```

But it does it abruptly.

Comment: [self scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath
            atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:NO];  why the animated property is "NO"?

Comment: I tried both YES and NO...I just posted NO in the question

Comment: You can try to scroll with delay "0.4", see what it does.. Make "withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade".

Comment: @user2384694 have you inherited the table view?

Comment: @user2384694 are you using UITbleViewController?

Comment: not using tableviewcontroller.....yes inhertied uitableview

Comment: I asked this as you have called the table view methods with self rather than tableview instance

Comment: @user2384694 have you tried using animateWithDuration: to scroll the table view?

Comment: I did...it did not work

Answer (score 0):

After inserting sections you can also scroll the table view to the intended index path using

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:2];

[UIView animateWithDuration: 1.0
                  animations: ^{
                      [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath
            atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:NO];
                  }
                  completion: ^(BOOL finished){
                  }
    ];
```

**Note**:

1) Insert the above code after `[self endUpdates];`

2) Please ensure that you keep the `animated` flag to `NO` using `scrollToRowAtIndexPath: atScrollPosition: animated:` while you are using it with UIView's `animateWithDuration: animations: completion:` API.

3) Also you can calculate the duration based on the distance (content size, height wise for vertical scroll), i.e duration can depend on the distance between source index path and destination index path.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please try below code.

[self beginUpdates];

/*
       Insert your sections
*/

[self endUpdates];

[self performSelector:@selector(scroll) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];

-(void)scroll 
{
    if([Your array count] > 0)
    {
        [YOURTABLENAME scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:2] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
    }
}

I Hope above code is work for you.
```

Thanks